# How to select odd or even items from a row in SQL?

Tags: sql, modulus, operation

I need only even or odd items, so I find modulus operation and this doesn't works

```
SELECT  * FROM table ORDER BY id WHERE MOD (num, 2) = 1 ASC;
```

Please help me, I'm noob in sql, as I haven't done much in it.

Answer (score 21):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table 
WHERE MOD (num, 2) = 1 
ORDER BY id ASC;
```

Will return all of the odd values of num.

Comment: If you have duplicate values you should add the DISTINCT option.

Answer (score 5):

for even

```
 where ([num]% 2) = 0
```

for odd

```
 where ([num]% 2) <>0
```

Answer (score 4):

For even, query:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  table_name 
WHERE 
  MOD(NUM, 2) = 0 
ORDER BY 
  ID ASC;
```

For odd, query:

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  table_name 
WHERE 
  MOD(NUM, 2) != 0 
ORDER BY 
  ID ASC;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MOD(num, 2) = 1 ORDER BY id ASC;
```

After fetching the final resultSet for the sql server based on where condition then only we can apply any ordering either `ASC` and `DESC`.